# How can i show a popup to user as a success message?

Tags: c#, popupwindow, xaf

everyone. We are using XAF framework in our project and I need to show a popup something like "Process was completed successfully" that indicates some process has been done successfully. Can you point any documentation or code snippet?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a possible implementation can be found at https://github.com/expand/eXpand/tree/master/Xpand/Xpand.ExpressApp/Xpand.ExpressApp/MessageBox

Comment: thank you for your comment. we solved the problem with a similar concept like yours. i think people will use it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i remember there is no option for showing message boxes in xaf. You need to create your own form and use it to show messages.